# How can we hide an entire folder of routes in expo-router?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, expo-router

The documentation covers how to [hide a single route](https://expo.github.io/router/docs/guides/tabs/#hiding-a-tab) in Tabs. Is there a way to hide an entire folder of routes?

I get this
`WARN  [Layout children]: No route named "customer/[i*" exists in nested children: ["(auth)/sign-in", "customer/[id]/details", "customer/[id]/create-order"...`

when I do this

```
          <Tabs.Screen
            name="customer/*"
            options={{
              href: null,
            }}
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

try to put a _layout.tsx file rendering a simple  inside the folder you want to hide, in this way Expo will recognize it as a route.

Comment: I have tried all these methods and none is working. is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you add a layout file inside your `customer` folder, then you can hide the entire folder of routes in Tabs with `name="customer"` (instead of `name="customer/*"`).

Answer (score 0):

So after, a lot of research, i found it.
We all want to group out files into modules, right?
Here is how I did it.

- `app/(public)/` #this is for grouping unauthenticated files
- `app/(core)/` #this is for the main folder for authenticated files.

Then inside the `(core)` i have other files and folders. now to hide the the folders and files in a folder called Projects I did this
Name folder as

```
/app/(core)/(Projects)/myFiles.
```

then in my app/(core)/_layout.jsx

```
<Tabs.Screen
      name="(Projects)"
      options={{
        
      }}
    <Tabs.Screen
      name="Settings"
      options={{
        
      }}
    />
```

then in the Projects folder
add another app/(core)/(Projects)/_layout.jsx like so:

```
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Layout = () => {
  return <Stack screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} />;
};

export default Layout;
```

To group the files and still hide them:

//create a folder say `Hidden` then go into this folder and add a _layout.jsx. then inside your Tabs _layout folder add this.

```
<Tabs.Screen
   name="(Hidden)"
    options={{
       href:null
      }}
  />
```